# Kali Linux not giving enough power to WiFi usb

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb, virtualbox, kali-linux

I tried connecting WiFi USB to Kali linux, as I need to directly access WiFi (like monitor mode).

The USB worked well in my host system (Debian "Buster"). The moment I started the VM (virtualbox, installed yesterday), the LED on the USB disappeared. Running `dmesg` on kali revealed code -110 which (as I searched for) means that the USB doesn't have enough power (as I guessed by the LED).

Virtual Box:

- Host: Debian 10 Buster (Running on ASUS Notebook (x555l))
- Guest: Kali linux
  (No new packages installed)

Any help how to fix this?

**Edit**:
Output of `dmesg | grep -i usb` is

```
[    1.382161] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    1.382185] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.382195] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.385721] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.399774] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0c.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.679571] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    1.679578] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.679583] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.679588] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-kali3-amd64 xhci-hcd
[    1.679593] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0c.0
[    1.687888] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.688269] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0c.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.688272] xhci_hcd 0000:00:0c.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    1.688399] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    1.688400] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.688401] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.688402] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-kali3-amd64 xhci-hcd
[    1.688403] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:0c.0
[    1.689901] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.022243] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.219416] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=80ee, idProduct=0021, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    2.219419] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
[    2.219421] usb 1-1: Product: USB Tablet
[    2.219423] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: VirtualBox
[    2.510996] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.510997] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.512527] input: VirtualBox USB Tablet as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0c.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:80EE:0021.0001/input/input6
[    2.512723] hid-generic 0003:80EE:0021.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [VirtualBox USB Tablet] on usb-0000:00:0c.0-1/input0
[    2.634316] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.656412] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0586, idProduct=3410, bcdDevice=48.10
[    2.656418] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=0
[    2.656421] usb 1-2: Product: ZyXEL G-202
[    2.656423] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: ZyDAS
[    4.825895] usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    4.908500] usbcore: registered new interface driver zd1211rw
[    6.628257] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_ub
[    6.628554] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_uphr
[    6.697265] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_ub
[    6.697287] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_uphr
[   11.966558] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_ub
[   11.966574] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_uphr
[   12.979481] usb 1-2: USB control request for firmware upload failed. Error number -110
[   12.979487] usb 1-2: Could not upload firmware code uph. Error number -110
[   12.980124] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_ub
[   12.980340] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_uphr
[   14.003301] usb 1-2: USB control request for firmware upload failed. Error number -110
[   14.003312] usb 1-2: Could not upload firmware code uph. Error number -110
[   24.008546] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_ub
[   24.008562] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_uphr
[   25.037494] usb 1-2: USB control request for firmware upload failed. Error number -110
[   25.037501] usb 1-2: Could not upload firmware code uph. Error number -110
[   25.038018] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_ub
[   25.038036] usb 1-2: firmware: direct-loading firmware zd1211/zd1211b_uphr
[   26.064054] usb 1-2: USB control request for firmware upload failed. Error number -110
[   26.064099] usb 1-2: Could not upload firmware code uph. Error number -110
```

Comment: Error 110 is timeout, not lack of power. True, the timeout might be caused by power drop or some such. See [kernel code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.108/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno.h#L93). Oh, and error codes in Linux kernel are often negated, that's normal.

Comment: Yes, but the LED would light up if it got power (even when the device isn't active and just receiving electricity)

Comment: I'm not staying that it is getting the power - clearly it's not. But 110 does not mean lack of power, it means timeout.

Comment: Going back to the topic of your answer: mind posting more output of `dmesg | grep -i usb`? Also, is this a notebook or a PC?

Comment: I edited the question with the info

Comment: I have a suspicion that there is a controllable overcurrent for the USB which is either not exposed to Kali or not set properly. Though I have no idea how to go on with this :/

Comment: I just installed the addon to virtualbox and then set the usb. Is there any config or something like that that could help? (Also the kali was downloaded from offensive-security page with the VM already set up)

Comment: Depending on the USB this is normal. The led isn't going to turn on if the drivers aren't installed for it. And especially not if you haven't configured the system properly. Run Kali from a bootable USB or install it dual boot alongside your main OS.

Comment: This might be virtualbox issue then, as when I used kali on windows host with vmware, it worked out of the box...